# Monit opening an URL when check fails

Tags: url, ubuntu, sms, monit

I love the site. It's a good place to look for answers. Thanks for that.

I am wrestling with a feature of munin on a test server.
It runs lighttpd, mysql, ssh, proftpd, postfix and dovecot.

If one of them fails, I would like to receive a text message next to the 'default' email. I have got an SMS gateway in use, with VoipBuster. If I request an url (as stated below) I will receive a text message.
https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&from=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxx&text=xxxxxx

I have tried including this in my monit config, but I just can't get it to work.

Here's what I tried.
Including a 'if failed then' under every check, like this:

```
check process lighttpd with pidfile /var/run/lighttpd.pid
        group lighttpd
        start program = "/etc/init.d/lighttpd start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/lighttpd stop"
        if failed host 178.21.118.206 port 80
        protocol http then restart
        if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
        if failed then (url https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&from=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxx&text=CHECK EMAIL -- SERVER ERRORS!)
```

But I keep getting errors like this when I am restarting.

```
/etc/monit/monitrc:194: Error: syntax error 'EMAIL'
```

I tried moving around with the 'if failed then' clause, but I literally don't know how to solve this anymore.

Comment: Does replacing a space with %20 work? e.g. ...&text=CHECK%20EMAIL%20--%20SERVER%20ERRORS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the possible solutions.
I ended up using Pushover, which is an app for mobile phones.
With his app you can send an email to a specific email address (built-in feature in Monit) and get push notifications on your mobile.

Comment: After using Pushover for a while I found Pushbullet, which offers more platforms. So people could check that out too